# Active Record - How to order by the difference in datetime (i.e. order by closest to a given datetime)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Let's say I want to find a model with the closest created_at to a given datetime, within some limits (e.g. within a 14 day period).

```
dt = some_datetime_in_the_past
query = Model.where("created_at >= ? AND created_at <= ?", dt - 7.days, dt + 7.days)
```

This would get all models that were created within 7 days of `dt`. I then want to find the model that's closest to dt. So something like this:

```
query.order("created_at - #{dt}")
```

Obviously that doesn't work or else I wouldn't be here, but I want to acheive something like that. Obivously a regular order by created_at wouldn't work, as that only finds the closest/furthest to now, but not to given `dt`.

Answer (score 1):

With the appropriate caveats that you need to be very careful when interpolating into a raw SQL fragment, you should be able to use:

```
query.order("CASE WHEN created_at > #{dt} THEN created_at - #{dt} ELSE #{dt} - created_at END")
```

(Last time I checked, PostgreSQL did not provide an `abs(interval)` function, because of reasons.)

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try using the absolute value of `created_at` and `dt`:

`.order("abs(created_at - #{dt})")`